# AngularJS deserialize $http JSON dates i18n

Tags: json, angularjs, mongoose, internationalization

I have a problem and I don't quite know how to deal with it. It must be a common problem, but I didn't find a good answer yet.

I'm coding a MEAN stack app, using Mongoose, and the problem I have is with the dates format when changing the language in my app.

The scenario is: The user can insert some data that has a Date field, for example their birthday. That field is then sent to mongoose in a specific format (yyyy-MM-dd) and it gets stored correctly in a Date field in mongoose. When the user searches for the data stored, I have an $http get request that get back the data in JSON format. Right before the data is send from the server, I have this in the JSON:

```
{datetime: '2015-11-13T20:00:00.000Z'}
```

And send it from nodejs like this:

```
return res.status(201).send(obj);
```

And when the Angular gets it, depending on the language I'm using in that moment, it resolves to a Date or an Invalid date. If the language I'm using is English, the resulting JSON has a valid Date in that field. If I change it to Spanish for example, then it results into an Invalid date field.
The code in Angular is this:

```
$http.get(url).then(function (result) {
    //here the result.data may have an Invalid Date field
    deferred.resolve(result.data);
}, function (error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
});
```

I set the language in my app with the help of angular-translate, and I use angular-i18n and momentjs also.

I've read on this and here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http it say that

> If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser.

I understand that the default parser detects the Spanish i18n and tries to parse the date as yyyy-dd-MM, and obviously gets an Invalid Date.

The question here is: How can I explicitly set all the dates parsed in Angular, to follow a specific format, like yyyy-MM-dd, regardless of the i18n used? I've seen this solution already, but doesn't work for me: http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html

Is there a better way to handle all this? Maybe store the dates in Mongo not as Date fields, but like Strings, using the JS `getTime()` function? 
This last method means that I would have to change all the dates in my app. It's a lot more work, but the result will be more standard, right?

Thank you!

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. If I call `res.status(201).send({ datetime: '2015-11-13T20:00:00.000Z' });` on Node, Angular gets datetime as a string '2015-11-13T20:00:00.000Z', which I was expecting.

Comment: If you use English as the translation language, Angular gets that valid datetime. If you use another, like Spanish, the parse fails. I don't know if it's for the angular-translate or the angular-i18n, but I get a, Invalid date, just like I explained earlier. Which of this ones did you use?

Comment: My understanding is that there should not be any date translation involved: Node sends a string and Angular receives a string. BUT: as you do have a problem, there must be something in-between. I created an example: https://github.com/masa67/NgDates. What did I miss?

Comment: It must be something wrong in your stack. If you convert these dates manually (like in `new Date(result.data.datetime);`) it has to work. Regardless of the language (this is ISO8601 format after all).

Comment: Hmm, yes there must be something else interfering. I just extended the project  @masa shared, including all language modules that I use in my project, and it's working fine. This is pretty strange. I'll look into my code. The problem must be on the server side. 
Thank you both for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Problem solved. If you are curious, the problem was with momentjs not handling the string dates too well, and it's a known issue: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407